# tensordot on 3-dim x 2-dim

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have `tensor_A` with shape `(batch_size, x_1, x_2)` and `tensor_B` with shape `(x_2, x_3)`. I would like to dot multiply each element of `tensor_A` with `tensor_B`. An example of this not using tensordot is like this:

```
product_tensor = np.zeros((batch_size, x_1, x_3))
for i in range(batch_size):
    product_tensor[i] = np.dot(tensor_A[i], tensor_B)
```

I am having trouble figuring out what the arguments for the `axes` parameter should be. From what I have read, `axes=1` means dot product, but I can't tell whether it's multiplying the first 2 axes of A with B or the last 2 axes of A with B.

I have tried `tf.tensordot(tensor_A, tensor_B[None, :, :, :], axes=1)` with no success as it seemed to reshape `tensor_A` into shape `(batch_size * x_1, x_2)` and `tensor_B` into shape `(1, x_2 * x_3`.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `matmul/@` handles batched well.  `A@B`.  `np.einsum` also gives good control over axis combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the desired result:

```
import numpy  as np

a = np.array([
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
])
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
print('a.shape = ', a.shape)
print('b.shape = ', b.shape)


# tensordot
c_tensordot = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=(1))

# loop method with dot
c_loop = np.empty([a.shape[0], a.shape[1], b.shape[1]])
for i in range(0,a.shape[0]):
    c_loop[i] = np.dot(a[i], b)


print('c_tensordot = ', c_tensordot)
print('c_loop      = ', c_loop)

print('c_tensordot.shape = ', c_tensordot.shape)
print('c_loop.shape      = ', c_loop.shape)

print('\nAre arrays equal: ', np.array_equal(c_tensordot, c_loop))
```